# Angular - wait on routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I have an app, that in it's "run" has an async http request.

The request is to validate the user and his permissions.

If I remove the async: true, it sends the request, but the router also fires, loading the template and initiating the controller.

Is there a way to tell the router to 'wait', and fire it manually when I am ready?
I don't want the controller to load into memory, because I don't know if this user has access to that module, and that module uses some global variables of the rootscope, loaded after the ajax response.

Comment: once u got response you can call the state.go("particluarpage) ryt , based on the access pass the params to page $state.go('dashboard.abc', {
    "permission" : responsevalues
   });

Comment: @gayathri Did not realy understand the solution. I am also using $routeProvider not $stateProvider